# $_FILES Not Working?

Tags: php, html

I am submitting files via this way, inside of a form (with a submit button, form tags, etc):

```
<fieldset>
        <input type="file" name="file" />
    </fieldset>
```

And I am trying to pull it/use it with PHP this way:

```
$file = $orgname."/".basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file);
```

And I am getting these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\generic\addorg.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\generic\addorg.php on line 46
```

What could be causing this? Everything I've looked into suggests it should work.

Comment: I'm not sure the exact problem, but a good debugging tool is to print_r your $_FILES and see what's inside.

Answer (score 26):

form needs to be set `enctype=multipart/form-data`

Comment: Seems to work, however now I am getting "unable to move" and "failed to open stream" errors.

Comment: probably a permissions issue jake

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your `<form...` specifies `enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 3):

Have you set the **enctype** attribute of your form to: **multipart/form-data** ?

```
<form action="/some_action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="some_name" value="Submit" id="some_name" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<form action="something.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5242880" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -4):

try flipping your slash since you are using a windows machine

```
$file = $orgname . '\\' . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Comment: Not only does this not matter, but by putting a backslash within double quotes, you have escaped the second quote.

Comment: You still need to escape the \